# How can I define a daysBetween function using the DataFrame-EC library in Java?

Tags: java

I have defined a column `StartDate` as follows for a DataFrame I am loading using the [dataframe-ec](https://github.com/vmzakharov/dataframe-ec) library.

```
schema.addColumn("StartDate", ValueType.DATE);
```

I would like to add a computed column named `DaysToEvent` but am unsure how to define a function leveraging the Java time library so the following expression code will work.

```
dataFrame.attachColumn(
        dataFrame.createComputedColumn(
                "DaysToEvent",
                ValueType.LONG,
                "daysBetween(toDate(2023, 3, 11), StartDate)"));
```

I saw there was a built-in function named `withinDays` but am hoping to not have to change the library to add this function. I tried defining the expression using Java Code inline but that didn't work.

```
dataFrame.attachColumn(
        dataFrame.createComputedColumn(
                "DaysToEvent",
                ValueType.LONG,
                "java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(toDate(2023, 3, 11), StartDate)"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your custom functions to the dataframe-ec expression DSL at runtime. Then these functions can be used just like those that come with the library out of the box in expressions like computed columns, filters, and so on. So you will be able to write code that looks like:

```
dataFrame.addColumn("DaysToEvent", "daysBetween(toDate(2023, 3, 11), StartDate)")
```

(this is a bit more streamlined than what you have in your example: you can call `addColumn` directly on a dataframe object and you don’t need to specify the type of a computed column as it is inferred from the expression you provide).

To add a function (in this case `daysBetween`) to the expression DSL you need to call the `addFunctionDescriptor` method on the `BuiltInFunctions` class.
You can look at the existing implementations in `BuiltInFunctions` (which also has examples of dealing with parameters, different types, validations, etc.) and also take a look at `RuntimeAddedFunctionTest`. In your case something like this should work:

```
BuiltInFunctions.addFunctionDescriptor(new IntrinsicFunctionDescriptor("daysBetween", Lists.immutable.of("date1", "date2"))
    {
        @Override
        public Value evaluate(EvalContext context)
        {
            LocalDate date1 = ((DateValue) context.getVariable("date1")).dateValue();
            LocalDate date2 = ((DateValue) context.getVariable("date2")).dateValue();

            return new LongValue(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2));
        }

        @Override
        public ValueType returnType(ListIterable<ValueType> paraValueTypes)
        {
            return LONG;
        }
    }
);
```

**Note:** I am the original author of the dataframe-ec library